# Getting the same value of the radio button selected using Val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and I wish to get the value of a radio button but it always gives me the same value ("floating") even though I select a different radio button and I run this function?!

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="license_floating" name="license" value="floating" class="realtime" />
<input type="radio" id="license_fixed" name="license" value="fixed" class="realtime" />
```

JS/JQuery:

```
alert($('form#quick input[name=license]').val());
```

The form is named quick, however, there are other forms on the page which have use the same IDs. But this shouldn't be a problem as I am referencing it correctly by referring to the form as well as the element ID.

*Should be asking for the selected one somehow?*

Really need help on this!

Thanks all

Comment: An ID must be unique in a document. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the selected radio button with [:checked](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/checked)

```
alert($('form#quick input[name=license]:checked').val());
```

This can also work if you want

```
alert($('form#quick input.realtime:checked').val());
```

But you state that #quick is in other places as well, as Gumbo pointed out in the comments, ID's should be unique.

Comment: How? Like this: $('form#quick input[name=license]:selected').val()